# R ggplot2: Labelling a horizontal line on the y axis with a numeric value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a horizontal line in a ggplot and I would like to label it's value (7.1) on the y axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(y=c(1:10),x=c(1:10))
h <- 7.1
plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() 
plot2 <- plot1+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept=h))
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just asked a related question about programmatically labeling multiple ablines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70747032/programmatically-label-multiple-ablines-in-r-ggplot2), if anyone in the future happens to be looking for that( as I was when I found this).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It's not clear if you want 7.1 to be part of the y-axis, or if you just want a way to label the line. Assuming the former, you can use `scale_y_continuous()` to define your own breaks. Something like this may do what you want (will need some fiddling most likely):

```
plot1+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept=h)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(c(seq(min(df$y), max(df$y), length.out=5), h)))
```

[image]

Assuming the latter, this is probably more what you want:

```
plot1 + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=h)) +
  geom_text(aes(0,h,label = h, vjust = -1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the scale_y_continuous solution.

Comment: What do you do if your line is an overlay over a bar chart, with factor x values.

Comment: Is it possible to have the label show up on the y-axis but on the right side of the plot instead?

Comment: How to change the font colour of that particular axis label, in this case, "7.1"?

Answer (score 8):

How about something like this?

```
plot1 + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=h), colour="#BB0000", linetype="dashed") + 
 geom_text(aes( 0, h, label = h, vjust = -1), size = 3)
```

Comment: unless you have your mind set on labeling it on the axis itself. You could increase the spacing of the tickmarks such that there is one at 7.1 but that would make your plot too busy.

Answer (score 8):

*Similar to Chase's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876602/4836511) with a change of using the existing labels.*

---

`ggplot_build(plot1)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$y.major_source` can be used to extract the exisitng labels and add new ones `h`.

```
plot1 + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=h)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(c(ggplot_build(plot1)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$y.major_source, h)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is a follow-up to [Prradep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46851686/9976891).

I think Prradep's answer works for an older version of ggplot2. I'm using ggplot2 version 3.1.0 and in order to extract the existing labels of `plot1` in that version you have to use:

```
ggplot_build(plot1)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.major
```

This only works for LINEAR AXES! If you have a non-linear y-axis (for example logarithmic), then ggplot2 stores where tick marks would be if the axis were linear in `$y.major`. The actual tick mark labels are stored as a character vector in `$y.labels`. Therefore, for a non-linear y-axis you need to use:

```
as.numeric(ggplot_build(cl.plot.log)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.labels)
```