# How to label a specific portion of a line graph in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

This is the code that I have so far. The idea with this was to investigate if there was a correlation between celebrity appearances in THY's commercials and if that had any impact on stock price. I have the dates of the Superbowl in question. What I would like to do is to highlight and then label when the Superbowl happened in relation to the plot, making it easier to illustrate if there was any correlation between the two. The dataframe: `THY_2_2016` is the final stock price by day for February 2016 for THY from Yahoo Finance. I downloaded this data and named the `THY_2_2016` object the object that contains that data. I also have similar code and plots for each following year up until February 2020.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggdark)

THY_2_2016 %>% ggplot(aes(Date, Close)) + 
  geom_line(color = "orange") +  
  labs(title = "Turkish Airlines' Final Daily Stock Price for February 2016", 
       subtitle = "Source: Yahoo Finance",
       y = "Final Stock Price (in Dollars)") + 
  dark_theme_gray() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

I know that the 2016 Superbowl happened on February 7, 2016, I would just like to label this even on the same plot and perhaps have a vertical line showing it. Otherwise, the plot just looks like a basic line graph that has no meaning. Could it be as simple as creating a new data frame with only one entry being February 7 and then adding that to the `ggplot` code? Doing so seems simple enough, but will that still allow me to label or point to that very easily? Any input would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Plot of final daily stock price]

Comment: One way would be to use an `xline` to mark the day:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-add-straight-lines-to-a-plot-horizontal-vertical-and-regression-lines

Comment: I would say this a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876501/r-ggplot2-labelling-a-horizontal-line-on-the-y-axis-with-a-numeric-value

Comment: @J.Doe. The `geom_vline()` function is what I was looking for exactly and I'm embarrassed that I haven't thought of it! The post that you referenced was also very helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all I think I figured it out! I played around with the annotate function as well as some arguments in the `geom_text` function but I couldn't get the results that I wanted. I discovered that the `geom_label` function is what I was really after. The function is simple and intuitive. I noticed that it was as simple using the x and y values that you wanted. This means that the `geom_label` function could be placed anywhere!

```
libraryggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggdark)

THY_2_2016 %>% ggplot(aes(Date, Close)) + 
  geom_line(color = "orange") + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.Date.character("2016-02-07"))) +
  geom_label(x = as.Date.character("2016-02-07"), 
             y = 6.7, label = "Superbowl 50", color = "white") +
  labs(title = "Turkish Airlines' Final Daily Stock Price for February 2016", 
       subtitle = "Source: Yahoo Finance",
       y = "Final Stock Price (in Dollars)") + 
  dark_theme_gray() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

I noticed that the `geom_vline` function is really finicky. I left the color argument alone and it looks like R or `ggplot` automatically selected a color that would work for it.

[image: corrected plot]

Answer (score -4):

Labelling a specific portion in graph using R is not posibble, you can alternatively take screenshot and edit pic

Comment: It’s definitely possible. We call these “annotations” [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/233-add-annotations-on-ggplot2-chart.html) is a link with basic annotation examples

Comment: This isn't correct. text(), mtext()... these are base operations.